# How do I center a donut chart inside an svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have the following tabpanel where I want to center the svg elements horizontally. My css works for the first of the svg elements (column chart) but not for the third (donut chart). Both sit inside divs that are inside the tab-content parent but only one is getting the css modifiers. How do I center the donut chart inside it's parent svg? [Here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/XWmPbVa) is the codepen of what I'm working on.

CSS:

```
.tab-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1">
      <h3>Column Chart <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
        <svg id="chart1" width="900" height="400"></svg>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
      <h3>Treemap <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
        <svg id="chart2" width="900" height="400"></svg>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
        <h3>Donut Chart <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
        <svg id="chart3" width="900" height="400"></svg>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
      <h3>Time Series <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
        <svg id="chart4" width="900" height="400"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the `flex` style to the `.tab-content`, which means that you are attempting to center the`.tabpanel` elements (in this case, they play the role of the flex items).

First of all, if you want to center elements inside the `.tabpanel` elements, you should apply the flex-box styling to it. You can go read more about flex here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Second of all, your SVG images are huge, but they don't actually take up all that space. For instance, your Donut Chart will be placed inside a large 900x400 box, while it is only taking up a small space in the top left corner. Flex-box will center your hole image, namely the 900x400 box, but the donut chart will be in the upper left corner of that large box.

My advice is that you should have the SVG's take up the whole box of the image, and scale them by need. Also, you might find it easier to control the width and height from CSS rather than a fix value like the one you have above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to center the donut chart by editing the transform to be translated closer to center of parent svg. The parent svg dimensions are 900 x 400.

Old transform:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(120,120)");
```

New transform:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(450,200)");
```